# pushing an array into another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following arrays.

```
var arr1=[1,2,3];   
var arr2=[4,5,6]; 
var arr3=[];
```

How would I push arr1 and arr2 into arr3 such that the result is:

```
arr3=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]];
```

not

```
arr3=[1,2,3,4,5,6];
```

which is produced when using the `.concat` method.

Comment: use `push()`???

Comment: How did you manage to get the result `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` in the first place…?

Comment: jee wiz i'm so out of it. i used the push() on the return statment.

Comment: @deceze part of a problem i am solving which is finding the lowest common multiple within a range.

Answer (score 5):

```js
var arr1=[1,2,3];   
var arr2=[4,5,6]; 
var arr3=[];
arr3.push(arr1,arr2);
console.log(arr3);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr1=[1,2,3];   
var arr2=[4,5,6]; 
var arr3 = [arr1,arr2];
console.log(arr3);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr3.push(arr1); 
arr3.push(arr2);
```

will do the work.
Anyway just follow http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp for further clarifications. 
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `push()` like in the other answers or this:

```
var arr1 = [1,2,3];
var arr2 = [4,5,6];
var arr3 = [arr1, arr2];
console.log(arr3);
```

Answer (score 0):

As others users have posted, the solution at your problem is use .push() method, but i would try to give you more information about these two methods.

I suggest you to read this [article](http://gunnariauvinen.com/difference-between-concat-and-push-in-javascript/), is very useful for me; I recap the main information for you below.

**PUSH METHOD**

Push method is used when you want add one or more elements, that were input arguments, to the array that invoked the method.

A simply example is the following:

```
var first_array = [1, 2, 3]; 
var result = first_array.push(4, 5, 6);
console.log(result); // 6 
console.log(first_array ); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

The one thing is not immediately apparent is that it returns the length of the array after adding the new values, not the modified array. (check third line: `console.log(result);`)

**CONCAT METHOD**

While push alters the array that invoked it, **concat** returns a new array with the original array joined with the array/s or value/s that were provided as arguments.

There are a couple of the things to note about **concat** and how it creates the returned array.

Both strings and numbers are copied into the array, which means that they if the original value is changed, the value in the new array will be unaffected.

*This is not true for objects.*

Instead of copying objects into the new array, the references are copied instead. This means that if the values of objects change in one array, they will also be changed in the other array, as they are references to the objects not unique copies.

A simply example is the following:

```
var test = [1, 2, 3]; // [1, 2, 3]  
var example = [{ test: 'test value'}, 'a', 'b', 4, 5];  
var concatExample = test.concat(example); // [1, 2, 3, { test: 'test value'}, 'a', 'b', 4, 5]  
example[0].test = 'a changed value';  
console.log(concatExample[3].test); // Object { test: "a changed value"}  
example[1] = 'dog';  
console.log(concatExample[4]); // 'a'
```

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oswf8n42/) for you with this example.

I hope that will be helpful